# current row returns null in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Can anyone tell me whats wrong in this code?

When I try to write values into the textbox I get an error: 'current row returns null in datagridview' This is an example that I just need to run, but I don't understand what's wrong.

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;////error
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text; //error
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = textBox3.Text;//error
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value = textBox4.Text;//error
    }

    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value = textBox5.Text;//error
    }

    private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value = textBox6.Text;//error
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen 'current row returns null in datagridview'

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Set the CurrentRow before setting its value.